# Split string in 2 with "." between

Tags: java, android, arduino

I have a Arduino sending GPS coordinates to an android app:

```
  bt_port.println(lat);
  bt_port.print ('.');
  bt_port.println(lon);
```

Receiving in the app:

```
    void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    stopThread = false;
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    Thread thread  = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread)
            {
                try
                {
                    int byteCount = inputStream.available();
                    if(byteCount > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                        inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                        final String emissorInput = new String(rawBytes,"UTF-8");
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        emissorGPS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        emissorGPS.append(emissorInput);

                                        emissorGPS.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                emissorGPS.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                emissorGPS.setText("");
                                            }
                                        }, 1500);
                                    }
                                });

                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopThread = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Already tried and the app crashes:

```
String[] test = emissorInput.split("\\.");
String part1 = test[0];
String part2 = test[1];
```

working parcialy since it just remove the "." but cannot split the string

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(emissorInput, "\\.");
String nextToken = tokens.nextToken();
```

Can any one guide me from where to go now!?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: are you sure your string is correct before trying to split it?

Comment: The "Receiving in the app:" code is working great and I get the code like it's being send from the Arduino; and with the tokenizer code take the "." off and works ok too, the main problem remains always.. cannot split that string!!

Comment: **NOTE:** the *String* received by **JAVA** is `LAT\r\n.LON\r\n`, because you use `Serial.println()`.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Thanks for the info, can you explain a little more; what should I add/change!?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your String comes in the form "lat.long" from Arduino you can use StringTokenizer because it returns empty string if splitted strings are null.

```
String inbound = "lat.long";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inbound, ".");
String lat = st.nextToken(); //this will contain "lat"
String helpDesk = st.nextToken(); //this will contain "long"
```

Comment: I changed my code to this and still crashes: 

//String inbound = "lat.lon";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(emissorInput, ".");
String lat = st.nextToken(); //this will contain "lat"
String lon = st.nextToken(); //this will contain "lon"

emissorGPS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
emissorGPS.append(lat + lon);

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash ?